# MultiLanguage Dynamic Website

Tags: php, zend-framework, web

I was wondering would would be a good way to build a dynamic site, with the possibility of adding languages and not changing the hole site for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mentioned you were using zend so you should be able to implement this.

Here you go Zend_Translate.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.introduction.html

Ive not used it myself but it says in the docs that it enables you to translate a view using whatever language adapter you wish to use.

Answer (score 0):

Better is to use CMS like Wordpress , zoomla and others.

Comment: i think for your req. better is to use cms, because you don't need to build any thing, any way if you want to use zend framework then you have to build complete cms for your own.